# autocomplete difficultes on getting the data from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi guys i have a problem on showing the data when i input any letters no data would complete the task 
 so it doesn't get any data from the database

Controller

```
<?php
//birds.php
class Birds extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('birds_view');
    }

    function get_birds()
    {
        $this->load->model('birds_model');
        if (!isset($_GET['term'])) {
            $q = strtolower($this->input->get('term'));
            $this->birds_model->get_bird($q);
        }

    }
}
```

--------------------Model

```
//birds_model.php (Array of Strings)

class Birds_model extends CI_Model
{

    function get_bird($q)
    {
        $this->db->select('birds');
        $this->db->like('birds', $q, 'after');
        $query = $this->db->get('birds');
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['birds'])); //build an array
            }
            echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
        }
    }
}
```

--------------------------------------View

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src=
    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type=
    "text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){              
          $("#birds").autocomplete({
            source: "birds/get_birds" // path to the get_birds method
          });           
        });           
    </script>    
    <title></title>
</head>    
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="birds" type="text"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Database

```
CREATE TABLE  birds (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  bird VARCHAR(50),
  aka VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  ) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

INSERT INTO birds (id, bird, aka) VALUES
(1, "Great Bittern", "Botaurus stellaris"),
(2, "Little Grebe", "Tachybaptus ruficollis"),
(3, "Black-necked Grebe", "Podiceps nigricollis"),
(4, "Little Bittern", "Ixobrychus minutus"),
(5, "Black-crowned Night Heron", "Nycticorax nycticorax"),
(6, "Purple Heron", "Ardea purpurea"),
(7, "White Stork", "Ciconia ciconia"),
(8, "Spoonbill", "Platalea leucorodia"),
(9, "Red-crested Pochard", "Netta rufina"),
(10, "Common Eider", "Somateria mollissima"),
(11, "Red Kite", "Milvus milvus"),
(12, "Hen Harrier", "Circus cyaneus"),
(13, "Montagu's Harrier", "Circus pygargus"),
(14, "Black Grouse", "Tetrao tetrix"),
(15, "Grey Partridge", "Perdix perdix"),
(16, "Spotted Crake", "Porzana porzana"),
(17, "Corncrake", "Crex crex"),
(18, "Common Crane", "Grus grus"),
(19, "Avocet", "Recurvirostra avosetta"),
(20, "Stone Curlew", "Burhinus oedicnemus");
```

my database name is birds
my table name is birds 
my problem is when ever i it does not found any of database

Comment: In your controller you wrote: if (!isset($_GET['term'])) Please remove the sign of exclamation (!). It should be if(isset($_GET['term']))

Comment: What makes you think that it couldn't find your database? Is there any error being thrown? If yes, where? Does it actually reach your controller? If yes, can you actually receive the value from your `$_GET['term']`?

Comment: Here are some more problems:
1) $this->db->select('birds'); The field name in your schema is BIRD and not birds. 
2) $this->db->like('birds', $q ,'after'); use it like this: $this->db->like('bird', $q);

Please first make sure that model gives you the desired data. We will then move forward to other things.

Comment: Use Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox Firebird to see if  you are reaching the controller at all. As JofyHS said. Save bet is to use - source: "<?php echo base_url('birds/get_birds'); ?>" .

Comment: there is no error the problem is that it doesn't get the data from the database because whenever i type any letter no suggested data being showed

Comment: the error show like this =//    GET http://localhost/ci_autocomplete/birds/get_birds?term=great 404 (Not Found)  jquery.js:8706

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but the basic step to identify the bug so as to resolve it easily.

1> First of all use Firebug to check for outgoing requests and call to which url is made and also the return value. 70% chance you get the error here itself.

2> Call the url in previous case manually in browser and check if you're getting expected result. Next 5% chance is that you're making mistake here.

3> If you are getting proper response use alert in js to check if you got the reply. The remaining 25% occurs because of autocomplete(js) being unable to parse the received string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Birds_model extends CI_Model
{

    function get_bird($q)
    {
        $this->db->select('bird as label, bird as value, id', false);
        $this->db->like('bird', $q, 'AFTER');
        $query = $this->db->get('birds');
        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){
            $data   = $query->result_array();
        }else{
            $data           = array();
            $data['label']  = "No results found";
            $data['value']  = "No results found";
            $data['id']     = '0';
        }

        return json_encode( $data );
    }
}

class Birds extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('birds_view');
    }

    function get_birds()
    {
        $this->load->model('birds_model');
        if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
            $q = strtolower($this->input->get('term'));
            echo $this->birds_model->get_bird($q);
        }

    }
}
```